# laravel broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden) while user is logged in

Tags: laravel

I am using `beyondcode/laravel-websocket` in my laravel app.

I am trying to use private channel for logged in user. but while the user is logged in. I face 403 error.

my channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{id}', function ($user , $id) {
    return $user->id == $id;
});
```

client side:

```
Echo.private('user.{{$loggedUser->id}}')
    .listen('MessageSent' , e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

the user utilizes the default guard. I also using multiguard system but for default user this shouldn't be a problem.

my BroadcastServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web','auth','auth:organ']]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

**note**: public channel works fine

Comment: Are you sure the private channel is accesed correct, as you use double {{, }} and single quotes..

i usually do something like this with string literals
`
echo.private(\`store.actions.user.${user.id}\`).listen('.store-action', (event) => ....

Comment: @DannyEbbers I already checked that. still 403.